# Error when using eas-CLI to build a Expo-managed React Native application

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage, eas

I'm a React Native enthusiast and I'm working on an Expo project. After successfully generating an APK using the eas-CLI, the app crashes shortly after opening due to a bug in the 'async storage' dependency. I created a new empty project and generated a working APK using the same commands, which suggests a specific problem with this dependency. I need help resolving this matter. Below are code snippets for comparison. Thanks for your help!

Specifications of my project:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ronaldinho-shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "Main.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.3",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The comparison of the compilation records (logs) between the two projects was the same. However, the only difference occurred in the "Run gradlew" topic, resulting in the following errors:

```
[stderr] 

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

[stderr] 

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

[stderr] 

Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

[stderr] 

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

[stderr] 

Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

[stderr] 

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```